# Xcode 11 Firebase auth for Mac app has error An error occurred when accessing the keychain

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, ios13, xcode11

I am turning iOS app to Mac app, when I run Xcode for **My Mac**, 
I was trying to login my app on Mac, when I press button login, below Error shows:

`An error occurred when accessing the keychain. The @c NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey field in the @c NSError.userInfo dictionary will contain more information about the error encountered`

**MacOS: 10.15.1
Xcode: 11.2.1**

It works totally fine on iPhone simulator or real iPhone, it only occurs when I try to run on Mac

I think this is a issue that Firebase does Auth does not really support Mac app that well.

PS: there is a question looks kind similar, but I don't really understand
[Firebase fails to configure and load the user on some devices running iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39653622/firebase-fails-to-configure-and-load-the-user-on-some-devices-running-ios-10)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `Keychain Sharing Capability` to the target's build settings. More context [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/3144#issuecomment-520530306).

Click the + Capability and then choose `Keychain Sharing Capability`

[image]

Comment: Could you pls be more specific how to add `Keychain Sharing Capability`

Comment: in my `Singing & Capebilities`, I don't see that option at all. only three big sections. **1.Signing**  **2.App Sandbox**  **3.Hardened Runtime**

Comment: Added a screenshot